# My cat nibbles me when I scratch myself

Tags: cats, behavior

quite a funny question for your, as I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Everytime I scratch myself our 9 months neutered male cat stops whatever he's doing, points at me and will run towards my hand, sometimes nibbling it, some other times patting it, as if he's trying to scratch it without using claws. He doesn't actually hurt me nor it seems like he wants to, it looks like he can't understand the concept of a human scratching himself and is curious about it.

So much so that I sometimes do it on purpouse. Has anyone ever seen a similar behaviour with a cat?

And no, I don't scold him for that. It's just too funny.

Comment: this  sounds like the start of a fantastic friendship :)

Comment: This remind me a bit. I had a cat that would use the kitty litter whenever I went to the toilet. We even tested it, pretending to go, get up, sit down again. She would hop into the litter box and start scratching the litter to go to the toilet.

Comment: He actually did the same thing when I scratched the floor. I've just found a new game to play with him!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probably just want to play and is attracted by your hand, try scratching the ground and he will probably do the same